# Show subscriber id in loop

Tags: wp-query, users

I want to show student (subscriber) id in a foreach loop. here is my code

```
$args = array (
    'role' => 'student'
);
$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$students = $wp_user_query->get_results();

if (!empty($students)) {
    foreach ($students as $student) {
        $student_info = get_userdata($student->ID);
        echo '<p class="username">' . $student_info->first_name . ' ' . $student_info->last_name . '</p>';
        echo $student_info->user_id;
     }
}else {
    echo 'No students found';
}
```

Student names are showing but the student id doesn't. Any idea how can I retrieve the id?

Comment: You're already using it in your loop... `$student->ID`

Comment: Just to clarify what @bosco said (all credit should go to him), you need to replace `echo $student_info->user_id;` with `echo $student->ID`.

Comment: @DmitriyDemir , any idea if i want to add dropdown filter i.e. by name, by roll etc to show student list ?

Answer (score 0):

You have already getting the student ID, Replace the following line of code

```
echo $student_info->user_id;
```

With

```
echo $student->ID;
```

Here's [a link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)!